# After Starting to Debug VS2017 ASP.NET Do not get this message

Tags: asp.net, angular, visual-studio-2017, chrome-debugging

After I F5 to debug in my ASP.NET 2.1/Angular 6.1 I do get the localhost server I request.  I do not get "Enable Chrome For Debugging with VS2017".  I am using VS2017 15.7.4

It be great to debug with Chrome and VS2017.  Here are some of my settings:

[image: VS2017->DEBUGGER->OPTIONS]

Answer (score 0):

I found out the source of not getting the pop up stating debugging with chrome.  After I checked the legacy box I got the pop-up.
[image]